# Error after cell insertion: invlalid number of sections

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

After receiving a new object, I call this func to insert a cell:

```
private func addCellToTheTop(recipe: Recipe) {
    guard let recipeTableView = self.recipeTableView else { return }
    recipesForShow.insert(recipe, at: 0)
    recipeTableView.beginUpdates()
    recipeTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
    recipeTableView.endUpdates()
}
```

But I get an error

[image]

Why the number of section does not match?

If it is important:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return recipesForShow.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return TableCellConfig.spaceBetweenCells
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerView = UIView()
        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        return headerView
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this exception because you are appending a new element to the array that is being used to determine the `numberOfSection` whereas you are inserting a new row into the `tableView`. To fix this you need to insert section instead of inserting new row, here's how:

```swift
recipeTableView.insertSections([0], with: .automatic)
```